# Start up boot for bootable usb

Tags: macbook-pro

I have  a old Macbook 4,1 currently running Lion. I tried to install Yosemite by creating a bootable USB (the process and the bootable USB is fine).
If I hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   and plug in the USB when starting the Mac it shows me a white screen not the choose menu for startup disk and if I do the same after loading the startup disk menu the USB is not shown there.
I tried the same USB in my Macbook Pro 2019 and it's working fine.

I tried all the fixes like  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>P</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>   but nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The last supported OS for the Macbook 4,1 is Lion, 10.7.5
See [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-white-13-early-2008-penryn-specs.html)

Additionally, Macs from before 2009 are quite difficult to persuade to boot from USB, they really want a CD/DVD - though in this case that point is moot.